# How to build custom grid

Tags: android, custom-component

I have a problem and i will be grateful if anyoune helps me.

Ok. I've started android programming 2 month ago. Now i am developing a simple game, nava battle. For this programm i need to build a grid, where i can place ships and coordinates. I can't seem to find out how I should be doing this?
I think i should build a custom view, which will do all that i need. If anyone could show some examle or explain how to build appropriate view i'll be happy

Answer (score 4):

IMO you should consider extending or at least using a `GridView` and place your UI components inside it. The Adapter backing the Gridview could contain information about the co-ordinates and Images(ships).

I think the following would be useful to you:
[Beginners tutorial on GridViews](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)
[Building custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)
This is an example of board game developed on Android:[Chess on Android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/honzovysachy/)